# Machine Learning Algorithm for Text Data

Tags: machine-learning, ssl-certificate

I want to make a prediction of whether an SSL certificate containing “PayPal” in the Subject Alternative Names is actually a certificate belonging to PayPal based on a combination of the text fields within the certificate. For example: if all of PayPals certificates are issued by DigiCert and we make a prediction on a certificate issued by Lets Encrypt containing “PayPal” in the SAN field, the certificate would likely not belong to PayPal.

What machine learning algorithms and techniques would be suited for this type of problem?

Comment: Hello, Which language you want to use? anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: I so far I have compiled a dataset of 50k phishing certificates and top 50k Alexa sites using HTTPS. I have used python with scikit learn and encoded each certificate authority as an attribute but I am questioning now if this is a good approach